# Why does byteArray have a length of 22 instead of 20?

Tags: java, encoding, string, arrays

We try to convert from string to `Byte[]` using the following Java code:

```
String source = "0123456789";
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16");
```

We get a byte array of length 22 bytes, we are not sure where this padding comes from.
How do I get an array of length 20?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[Alexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/convert-string-to-byte-in-java#228998) explains why it's there, but not how to get rid of it. You simply need to specify the endianness you want in the encoding name:

```
String source = "0123456789";
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16LE"); // Or UTF-16BE
```

Answer (score 25):

May be the first two bytes are the [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). It specifies the order of bytes in each 16-bit word used in the encoding.

Answer (score 7):

Try printing out the bytes in hex to see where the extra 2 bytes are added - are they at the start or end?

I'm picking that you'll find a [byte order marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) at the start (0xFEFF) - this allows anyone consuming (receiving) the byte array to recognise whether the encoding is little-endian or big-endian.

Answer (score 7):

UTF has a byte order marker at the beginning that tells that this stream is encoded in a particular format. As the other users have pointed out, the 
1st byte is 0XFE
2nd byte is 0XFF
the remaining bytes are 
0
48
0
49
0
50
0
51
0
52
0
53
0
54
0
55
0
56
0
57