# Does Java have a function to convert a string to a byte array?

Tags: java

Is there any function in Java that converts a string to a byte array?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to byte\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/convert-string-to-byte)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: [`String.getBytes`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)). You really, really want to specify the character encoding when you do so though - using the platform default encoding is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Ideally, it's best to specify the encoding via a [`Charset`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) - that way you don't need to worry about the [`UnsupportedEncodingException`](http://UnsupportedEncodingException) which can be thrown by the overload of `getBytes` which just takes a String with the character encoding *name* as an argument.

EDIT: Based on your comment, it looks like you want to parse a hex string into a byte array. (It would have been useful to say so in your question.) `String.getBytes` is inappropriate for this - I don't believe there's anything which does this in the standard libraries, but the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) library makes it pretty easy:

```
byte[] data = Hex.decodeHex(text.toCharArray());
```

Comment: @silverkid: You mean you want to *parse* a string of hex digits into a byte array? Editing...

Comment: yes i have a string of hex digits that i want to convert to byte array

Comment: for example my string is 95A8EE8E89979B9EFDCBC6EB9797528D

Comment: Using the deprecated version of the getBytes method is 10x faster than newer, correct versions.  We use the older method in logging code where encoding issues are not a concern. ref: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Performance/

Comment: Where can encoding issues not be a concern? If you don't care about the output, why bother calling the method? I'd also question the wisdom of trusting performance advice from 12 years ago...

Answer (score 1):

String.getBytes()?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
"whatever".getBytes()
```

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use the platform default encoding.