# How to perform XOR operation in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I want to know whether there is any method to perform XOR operation in J2ME?

Comment: Why not use bitwise XOR operator `^` ?

Comment: I want to XOR two strings in J2ME

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5126616/977676

Answer (score 0):

`!=`'s [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table) is the same as XOR.