# How to achieve php ^ in java

Tags: java, php

I want achieve a encrypt function in java ,
I known in PHP I can use `^` like

```
$encrypt ="abcd" ^ "qwe";
$decrypt = $encrypt ^ "qwe";
echo $encrypt;
```

Result:

> abcd

But I dont know how to achieve `^` in java

and how to make `"abcd"^"qwe"` in java

Comment: I hope you realise that this is rather weak 'encryption'.

Comment: The `^` is an XOR (exclusive or), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126616/xor-operation-with-two-strings-in-java