# How to get size in bits Java

Tags: java, string, size, endianness

How to get a size of String in 64 bits(not bytes)in big endian order)?
I have never done this kind of operations in Java. Thanks for any help : ).

Comment: See [Isn't the size of character in Java 2 bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078314/isnt-the-size-of-character-in-java-2-bytes)

Comment: Explanation, since OP doesn't care to give one: he wants the integer that is the string length (in bits) encoded into a stream of 64 bits, big-endian.

Comment: I gave all the explanation. I want size of one String in the 64bits format.
for example 010 this is 2 bits but in 3 bit format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java works internally always using BigEndian order even if the platform like x86 uses LittleEndian.

In Java 64bit values are stored in the `long` data type.

Now the final question is what you want to measure. In a String you can count the number of characters, or the number of bytes the String takes when encoding it using a specified encoding (e.g UTF-8, UTF-16, ISO-8859-1, ...).

Assuming you want to count the number of characters in a String and you want to get the number as a 64bit number you can use the following code:

```
String myString = "abcdefgh";
long charCount = myString.length;
```

If you want to write `charCount` into a file or into a network connection you can use DataOutputStream for getting a BigEndian representation:

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(streamToWriteTo);
out.writeLong(charCount);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this:

```
String source = "0123456789";
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
int sizeInBits = byteArray.length * 8;
```

Source: [Why does byteArray have a length of 22 instead of 20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/convert-string-to-byte)

Comment: Right so multiply by 8.  A byte is 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Eh?  Strings can only either be measured in chars, or in bytes, and that only once you specify a specific charset for the encoding.

For the latter, it's just `string.getBytes(charset).length`.

It might help if we knew what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Well, with bytes you can always convert to bits.

Comment: OP is obviously pushing a string into a bit stream. He needs to encode its length (in bits) into a 64-bit big-endian integer (again accessible as a bit stream), and then he'll send the string itself as a bitstream (that was his earlier question).