# How to convert String to byteArray and byteArray to String Array in java?

Tags: java, android, string, arrays

I want to convert String to bytearray in java..

For Example i want output like the following :

```
String s = "82,73,70,70,90,95,3,0,87,65,86";
```

Now the logic is , i want same String value in bytearray value like

```
byte[] b ={82,73,70,70,90,95,3,0,87,65,86};
```

`b = s.getBytes();` doesn't  return the same value...it returns each string of byte array value

Any help would be appreciated lot

Comment: What range of values can be in the input? What is the minimum and maximum possible value of your integers?

Comment: range of values will be around 2048 or 4096

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can try to split your `String` with `,` and then in loop **parse** each number with static method `Byte.parseByte(<el>);`

```
String source = "1,2,3,4,5";
String[] temp = source.split(","); // this split your String with ,
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[temp.lenght];
int index = 0;
for (String item: temp) {
   bytesArray[index] = Byte.parseByte(item);
   index++;
}
```

Also have look at

- [`Convert string to byte[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/convert-string-to-byte)
- [`Byte order mark`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark)

Answer (score 3):

Split the `String` by comma into `String array` and parse it to `Byte`.

```
        String s = "82,73,70,70,90,95,3,0,87,65,86";
        String[] splitedStr = s.split(",");
        byte[] b = new byte[split.length];
        int i=0;
        for (String byt : splitedStr) {
                 try{
            b[i++]=Byte.parseByte(byt);
                 }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.split(",")
```

returns an array of strings containing your single numbers.

```
Byte.parse()
```

parses your string to byte values. Iterate in a loop over all elements an fill your byte array.

Answer (score 0):

## #  **How to convert String to byteArray and byteArray to String Array in java?**#

```
String passwordValue="pass1234";

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

        sharedPreferences = getActivity.getSharedPreferences("key",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        byte[] password = Base64.encode(passwordValue.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        editor.putString("password", Arrays.toString(password));

        editor.commit();

        String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");

        if (password != null) {

        String[] split = password.substring(1, password.length()-1).split(", ");

        byte[] array = new byte[split.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {

        array[i] = Byte.parseByte(split[i]);

        }

        byte[] decodeValue = Base64.decode(array, Base64.DEFAULT);

        userName.setText("" + new String(decodeValue));

        }  
        Output:-

        password:-"pass1234"  

        Encoded:-password: 0 = 99
        1 = 71
        2 = 70
        3 = 122
        4 = 99
        5 = 122
        6 = 69
        7 = 121
        8 = 77
        9 = 122
        10 = 81
        11 = 61
        12 = 10

        Decoded password:-pass1234
```