# Implementing RSA algorithm with java

Tags: java, string, integer, rsa

I am trying to implement the RSA algorithm with java.
I understand the mathematical algorithm , what I do not understand is how to convert a message of string to cipher text of big integer.

- Do I encrypt and decrypt all message or cipher text as one huge integer?
- how do I convert string to integer and integer to string?

Comment: `BigInteger(String val) `?? because to convert from plaintext to cyphertext is the entire RSA algorithm.

Comment: "how to convert a message of string to cipher text of big integer" Soo, basically you're asking "how do I encrypt it?" You really need to reword your question. It's very vague. One tip: don't use a `BigInteger` to store your encrypted output. Use a `byte[]`.

Comment: The question seems quite clear to me and I even have an answer, so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: can you post it here for now?

Comment: @JamesKPolk can you please comment it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the typical way is to convert a string to a byte array ( [Why does byteArray have a length of 22 instead of 20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/convert-string-to-byte) ) and then turn the byte array into the numeric type that you want ( [Convert a byte array to integer in java and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619058/convert-a-byte-array-to-integer-in-java-and-vise-versa) ), i.e. int,long,double,...

Comment: and then apply the rsa algorithm for each byte separately? for each char? word? message? that is the part i don't understand.

Comment: And then apply RSA to each integer.  So once you get your string, say 16 bytes of data, that converts into 4 integers.  You apply RSA to your 4 ints, and then convert those 4 ints into a byte array which is your encrypted message.