# Java: Conversion between string and byte[]

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does byteArray have a length of 22 instead of 20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/why-does-bytearray-have-a-length-of-22-instead-of-20)

I just cant figure this out Why Am I getting an error when converting like this

```
String mystring = "This is a String";
Log.v("string:", mystring);
Log.v("byte then string:", mystring.getBytes().toString());
```

The output is as follows

```
String: This is a string
byte then string: [B@44ecc390
```

Can anyone help ? I actually just want a string to be converted to bytes and the again to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

`Log.v("byte then string:", new String(mystring.getBytes()));`

Comment: No, you shouldn't - that will use the platform default encoding, which is almost never appropriate.

Comment: Assuming the method used was `byte[] bytes = String.getBytes()`, it consistent to use `new String(bytes)` otherwise, `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` should be used in the first place.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes it is true, I was giving an example. You should always specify encoding when converting byte array to string.      new String(byteArray, "UTF-8").

Comment: @aymeric: It's only consistent if the bytes were obtained on a platform which uses the same encoding. I would personally always specify the encoding explicitly, even if it's *explicitly* saying "use the platform default". That states intentions more clearly, IMO.